# A program does not work on one of the vmware servers

Tags: .net, debugging, vmware

The VB.NET exe runs fine on one of the VMware servers but gives the following message on the clone of the same. There are no event entries and the program does not even start.

Its running on Windows server 2003. Any thoughts on how to debug/tackle this?

[Program Name] has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the invenience.

If you were in the middle of something, the information you were working might be lost.
[CLOSE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you cloned the machine, did you do a sysprep to generate a new machine name and new SID?

If not, you could run into weird issues.

[This vmware thread](http://communities.vmware.com/message/309350) contains a howto for cloning machines

Comment: It was MSMQ. The App did not have access/permissions to create the required queues. Some thing that took 12 hours of my time :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked in the Application Event Log? Unhandled .NET exceptions will be logged there. Otherwise, you could registered some logging code to the Application.UnhandledException event.

Comment: Well there are no traces of the event log. None of my code gets hit.I had put a line of code that writes to event log on InitializeComponent and nothing happens.